# What are some alternative words for "people"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

In the context of "people who learn a foreign language".

For example:

Most of the time, people learn a foreign language for professional reasons.

Which words can replace the word "people" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is "individuals," another is "persons". However, we really need to know what "kind" of "people" you are referring to to be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I mean "people who learn a foreign language."

Comment: Perhaps "professionals," or "scholars" might work.

Comment: Your answer was helpful in two ways. First, I was able to find more words when I think about the context, "what kind of people I am referring to". Also, individuals is indeed a more decent word to use here. So, thank you!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a more decent word", but there is nothing at all wrong with the word *people* in your sentence.

Comment: Or you could say ". . . *students* of foreign languages have professional reasons."

Comment: Glad to be of help~!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the word *people* or one of its synonyms at all if you put the sentence into the passive:

> Most of the time, a foreign language is learned for professional
>   reasons.